# Controlling volume level & playback with Logitech Revolution MX mouse buttons

Tags: 11.04, mouse, logitech, playback

On Windows, I use the extra buttons of the Logitech Revolution MX to play/pause media playback, and to control volume (level up/down and mute/unmute.)

I cannot seem to find a way to reproduce this behaviour in Ubuntu 11.04.

Specifically I use the thumb wheel to control volume, and the search button to play/pause music.

The thumb wheel seems to have no function, but some applications register it as a click.  The search button launches 'search for files'.

Is it possible to re-map these settings?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the handy utility [**btnx**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/btnx) [image: Install btnx] does the job quite well.

[See this Ubuntu Forums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=455656)

It's worth getting both `btnx` and `btnx-config`.  The latter provides a UI for discovery of mouse buttons, and subsequent configuration.

I managed to achieve the setup I described in the question, minus the play/pause mapping of the search button (this wasn't detected by the `btnx-config`) by mapping the following key commands:

```
KEY_VOLUMEUP
KEY_VOLUMEDOWN
KEY_MUTE
KEY_NEXTSONG
KEY_PREVIOUSSONG
```